# Reading from a CSV File in VB.Net where commas may exist in the data

Tags: vb.net, csv

I am reading data in from a text file.  I know that each piece of data is separated by a comma and it looks like this in the text file:

```
 "Requisition","Supplies Req GL.pdf","05/28/2014","8,200.00","0510","86107RC"
```

Here's where I am drawing a blank.  The 4th piece of data on the line can contain commas, so when I do a split on the data, it also splits that piece as well.

How can I read this in, separate the data and also keep column 4 in tact.

Comment: Look into the [TextFieldParser](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cakac7e6.aspx)

Comment: As an alternative, there is an overload of [String.Split](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf(v=vs.110).aspx) which accepts multiple character strings as delimiters (ie: `","`).

Comment: Then the way the file was built is flawed. I would have removed the quotes also.

Comment: TextFieldParser worked like a charm ... thanks Plutonix

Answer (score 1):

If you know it's that field, then just join them together... a little hokey but it works:

```
    Dim inLine As String()
    Dim columns As New List(Of String)
    Using sr as As New IO.StreamReader(args(0))
        While Not sr.EndOfStream
            inLine = sr.ReadLine.Trim().Split(CChar(","))
            columns.Add(inLine(0))
            columns.Add(inLine(1))
            columns.Add(inLine(2))
            If inLine.Length > 6 Then
                columns.Add(inLine(3) & inLine(4))
                columns.Add(inLine(5))
                columns.Add(inLine(6))
            Else
                columns.Add(inLine(3))
                columns.Add(inLine(4))
                columns.Add(inLine(5))
            End If
        End While
    End Using
```

Comment: why not use the `Using` blocks for the `StreamReader`?